# What to replace eregi() with?

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

What is eregi() replaced with in this instance?

```
// get value of text inbetween tags
function getContentByTag($tag1, $tag2, $string)
{
    if (eregi("$tag1(.*)$tag2", $string, $out)) {
        $outdata = $out[1];
    }
    return $outdata;
}
```

This post is not a duplicate post as the 3rd example within the referenced post the answer is for that specific usage. I'm guessing my usage is different as the referenced post answers are not working for me.

Comment: I ended up using:

`function getContentByTag($tag1, $tag2, $string)
{
    if (preg_match("'$tag1(.*?)$tag2'si", $string, $out)) {
        $outdata = $out[1];
    }
    return $outdata;
}`

Comment: No, imagine your `$tag` contains a `'` char. And you will get the same warning/error as you got with `/`. Use `preg_match('/' . preg_quote($tag1, '/') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote($tag2, '/') . '/si', $string, $out)`.

Comment: OK. Got ya @WiktorStribiżew. Will give that a shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7 you must replace it with

```
preg_match("/$tag1(.*)$tag2/i", $string, $out)
```

Comment: Well, now I am receiving error:

`Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'c' in /tracker.php on line 293`

Comment: what are the values of $tag1 and $tag2 ?

Comment: <center> and </center>